# how to have gson expect an array of arrays of objects?

Tags: java, android-studio, gson, retrofit

Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

I get this error because gson expects an object but since response from API starts with array it throws error. I 've looked at many answers on these questions but none seem to work/are understandable. the API returns an array of arrays of objects. (an array of objects for every sensor: temperature, humidity, ...). how should I change my code so it expects an array of arrays of objects?

```
[[
{"_id":"6022366801ad473cd0160e5d","time":"2020-03-11T18:07:44.000Z","value":"15","unit":"°C"}, 
{"_id":"602238f413fadf4bf04df86f","time":"2020-03-11T18:07:44.000Z","value":"15","unit":"°C"}, 
{"_id":"602238f613fadf4bf04df870","time":"2020-03-11T18:07:44.000Z","value":"15","unit":"°C"}, 
{"_id":"602934f9f8686e39800e4d2b","time":"2020-03-11T19:07:44.000Z","value":"15","unit":"°C"}, 
{"_id":"602934fdf8686e39800e4d2c","time":"2020-03-11T19:07:44.000Z","value":"15","unit":"°C"}, 
{"_id":"602934fef8686e39800e4d2d","time":"2020-03-11T19:07:44.000Z","value":"15","unit":"°C"}, 
{"_id":"60293589f8686e39800e4d36","time":"2020-03-11T18:07:44.000Z","value":"-2","unit":"°C"}, 
{"_id":"60293589f8686e39800e4d37","time":"2020-03-11T18:07:44.000Z","value":"-2","unit":"°C"}, 
{"_id":"602935adf8686e39800e4d43","time":"2020-03-11T18:07:44.000Z","value":"-2","unit":"°C"}
],[...]]
```

.

```
 public void GetDayFromAPI(){
         Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                 .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.106:3000/api/")
                 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                 .build();

         JsonPlaceholderApi jsonPlaceholderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceholderApi.class);
         Call<List<SensorPost>> call = jsonPlaceholderApi.getposts();
         call.enqueue(new Callback<List<SensorPost>>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(Call<List<SensorPost>> call, Response<List<SensorPost>> response) 
             {
                 if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                     textViewResult.setText("code: " + response.code());
                     return;
                 }
                 List<SensorPost> posts = response.body();
                 for (SensorPost post : posts){
                     String content = "";
                     content += "Unit: " + post.getUnit() + "\n";
                     content += "Value: " + post.getValue() + "\n";
                     content += "Time: " + post.getTime() + "\n\n";

                     textViewResult.append(content);
                 }
             }

             @Override
             public void onFailure(Call<List<SensorPost>> call, Throwable t) {
                 textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
             }
         });
     }
```

Comment: It _may be_ but _should not be_ changed from `List<SensorPost>` to `List<List<SensorPost>>`. Since it looks like you have the server installed in your local network, I'm assuming you may also be able to change its source code to get rid of outer array so that the response would be an array of objects rather than an array of an array of objects.

Comment: yes but you can't "push" anything to {}

Comment: Elaborate please. I still don't understand why your server sends `[[a, b, c, ...]]` instead of a more natural `[a, b, c, ...]`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was wrong: it does not send `[[a, b, c, ...]]` but it actually sends `[[a, b, c, ...], [d, e, f, ...], ...]`. Your Android app then has to deserialize a list of lists. By default (and there are no extra type adapters registered in your Gson instance, not sure if you're using `@JsonAdapter` though) `SensorPost` should be encoded with `{...}`, but your server responsds with an array of arrays, so I'm almost sure that `List<List<SensorPost>>` will work for you.

Comment: List<List<SensorPost>> fixed it thanx